# VBA MS ACCESS: How can I fix first condition in if?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've got an `if`. In the first condition I'm using a `Dlookup` function in order to check if the value of a text in a form is different from a certain table I have, but that condition is not being taking.

I've changed the `<>` operator to `=` but I still have the same result. It never goes to the `Else` part.

```vb
 Private Sub btn_Cambiar_Click()

    On Error Resume Next

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    Dim CambiarContraseña As String
    Dim coincidenContraseñas As Variant

    CurrentDb.Execute dbFailOnError

    If (DLookup("[Contraseña]", "tbl_Usuarios", "[Contraseña] <>'" & Me.txt_Contraseña.Value & "'")) Then

        MsgBox "¡La contraseña no coincide!!/"
        Me.txt_Contraseña.SetFocus

    Else
            CambiarContraseña = _
            "UPDATE tbl_Usuarios SET Contraseña = txt_Contraseña_Nueva.value WHERE ID_Usuario = txt_Usuario"

            DoCmd.RunSQL CambiarContraseña

            MsgBox ("Contraseña cambiada.")

            txt_Contraseña = Null
            txt_Contraseña_Nueva = Null
    End If    

End Sub
```

I expect that this `if` must go directly to the `else` part because the text I enter in the form is exactly the same text that I have in my table:

[image: tbl_Usuarios]

Comment: Think that you need to say `if dcount` then....

Comment: Do you mean replace or add that function? Why I do need to say that? Since that function counts the number of registers

Comment: Replace Dlookup as Dlookup will return a value, so not sure how it will work with multiple returns, you just want to see if it exists in the table, so use dcount, 0 means it doesn't exist and >0 means it does exist.  I may not have understood your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the DLOOKUP will return a value if your pattern matches. If it is not found DLOOKUP should return a null. So in your `If` you want to look for that null.

Like this:

```
If IsNull(DLookup("[Contraseña]", "tbl_Usuarios", "[Contraseña]='" & Me.txt_Contraseña.Value & "'")) Then
```

Comment: Yes, now the respective record on the field Contraseña is being changed. But this happens all the time. I mean, in the table the password is _123_ but if for example I type 12345 it with always go to the else part, So, I do not see why it does not stop when there is no coincidence. Should just pop up the first `MsgBox`

Comment: To see what is going on use `Debug.Print Me.txt_Contraseña.Value`. You can do this for everything and visually see the values you are working with. Read this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this

```
  If (Nz(DCount("[CID_Usario]", "tbl_Usuarios", "[Contraseña] <>'" & Me.txt_Contraseña.Value & "'"),0) > 0) Then ...
```

Comment: I had the same result as the correction of the first answer. Your suggestion looks a bit complex